# Установить фокус на JTextField в JOptionPane, а не на кнопках управления

Tags: java, swing, awt

К примеру создаю диалоговое окно с кастомной панелью.

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    modalPanel.createInputSchemaNamePanel(),
                    "Ввод значений:", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

И код самой панели:

```
private JLabel lNameSchema = new JLabel("Название схемы:");

private JTextField tfNameSchema =  new JTextField();

public JPanel createInputSchemaNamePanel(){

    panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    setStaticSize(lNameSchema, 150, 20);
    setStaticSize(tfNameSchema, 150, 23);

    setInPanel(lNameSchema, tfNameSchema, panel);

    return panel;
}
```

Можно ли как-то извернуться и сделать что бы при открытии этого диалогового окна, фокус был на tfNameSchema, а не кнопке "Готово"?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот здесь вроде победили: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774610/joptionpane-showconfirmdialog-multiple-inputs-focus-text-field Сам не проверял, посмотрите

Comment: @defaultlocale Спасибо большое! В голову не пришло искать на enSO